# How to skip test api docs in maven-javadoc-plugin?

Tags: maven-3, maven-site-plugin, maven-javadoc-plugin

I would like to skip generating 'testapidocs' folder in my 'target/site' folder after executing 'clean skip:skip' with following configuration.

**Build Configuration:**

```
<build>
<plugins>
    .................
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
   .........
</build>
```

**Reporting Configuration:**

```
   <reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

When i ran 'clean site:site' it is creating the following folders under 'target' directory:

**target/site/apidoc**

**target/site/testapidocs** - would like to skip this one

Answer (score 8):

The [Selective Javadocs Reports](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/selective-javadocs-report.html) told us as

> To run the Javadocs reports selectively, you need to include only the Javadocs reports that you prefer. As said in the [FAQ](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/faq.html#Where_in_the_pom.xml_do_I_configure_the_Javadoc_Plugin), the configuration depends on the `<build/>` tag or `<reporting/>` tag used.

#### Using `<build/>` Tag

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Default configuration for all reports -->
          ...
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>javadoc</goal>
              <goal>test-javadoc</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <configuration>
              <!-- Specific configuration for the given reports -->
              ...
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

#### Using `<reporting/>` Tag

```
<project>
  ...
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Default configuration for all reports -->
          ...
        </configuration>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <id>default</id>
            <configuration>
              <!-- Specific configuration for the given reports -->
              ...
            </configuration>
            <reports>
              <report>javadoc</report>
              <report>test-javadoc</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
          <reportSet>
            <id>aggregate</id>
            <configuration>
              <!-- Specific configuration for the given reports -->
              ...
            </configuration>
            <reports>
              <report>aggregate</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
  ...
</project>
```

I hope this may help.